# Circle CI: Can't connect to MySQL through docker instance?

Tags: mysql, docker, circleci

I'm trying to deploy a MySQL docker image, create a database, and test-run my migrations and seeders although its complianing it just can't access the MySQL server running on 127.0.0.1:3306, is there something I'm missing?

I get:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -psecret dbname < output/migrate.sql
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

Here is my circleci config:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  migrate-seed:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/base:2022.10
      - image: cimg/mysql:8.0
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
          MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: sudo chmod +x scripts/dump-all
      - run: mkdir output
      - run: scripts/dump-all
      - run: sudo apt-get update
      - run: sudo apt-get install -y mysql-client
      - run:
          name: Run Migrations
          command: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -psecret dbname < output/migrate.sql
      - run:
          name: Run Seeders
          command: mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -psecret dbname < output/seed.sql
workflows:
  database:
    jobs:
      - migrate-seed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a step that ensures the DB is ready before attempting to connect to it:

```
  - run:
      name: Waiting for MySQL to be ready
      command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:3306 -timeout 1m
```

Place it anywhere before your *"Run Migrations"* step.

Answer (score -1):

*It is probably not related to your problem but* in some cases you need to reinstall docker in you container to make it work:

```
    steps:
      - run:
          name: Reinstall Docker to fix an issue with port sharing
          command: apt update && apt install --reinstall docker.io --yes
```